# Проблема с заменой фрагмента

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragment

Имеется класс WorkoutDetailFragment который наследуется от Fragment.
При попытке замены этого фрагмента выводится ошибка

```
" Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'com.hfad.workout.WorkoutDetailFragment', required: 'android.app.Fragment'"
```

Код замены:

```
public void itemClicked(long id){
    WorkoutDetailFragment details = new WorkoutDetailFragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    <методы для добавления информации в фрагмент details>
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container,details); //тут возникает ошибка
}
```

В чём у меня недочёт?

Comment: Ну `getSupportFragmentManager()` же :)

Comment: Точно, забыл) Спасибо, снова выручили)